# Is there an issue with the sandbox PayPal IPN?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have been testing the PayPal Sandbox IPN and for the past week the code was working fine, while today suddenly it doesn't work anymore. I have not done ANY changes, so I don't know what's wrong.

When I use the simulator it works

```
173.0.81.1 - - [10/May/2015:03:44:28 -0700] "POST /pp_paypal.php HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "-"
```

But when I test it with a Sandbox transaction it doesn't.

Is the Sandbox IPN down or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue... I guess they have a problem. 
It happend at the same moment I changed my host server so I spent whole weekend trying to fix it when I finally **noticed all of my IPNs in history has "Queued" status**. 
Check if yours have the same. (login to bussiness account -> History -> IPN History)